# ggplot2, facet_grid, free scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following example, how do I get the y-axis limits to scale according to the data in each panel?

```
mt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
```

Neither of these will do it:

```
mt + facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scales="free")
mt + facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scales="free_y")
```

Comment: Anyone have any idea what the intended purpose is of the `scales` argument for `facet_grid`?

Comment: @geotheory it's in the docs. The scales argument is for freeing the x, y, or both scales for each facetted plot. Your options are 'fixed' (default), 'free_x', 'free_y', or 'free' for both. Use it when the ranges of your variables vary greatly and need to be freed.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you have only one y axis, using your way. Did you try something like this?

```
mt + facet_grid(cyl ~ ., scales="free")
```

Comment: I see - so it doesn't scale each panel by by rows or columns... in the case facet_wrap() also works I guess.

Comment: How about plotting the same data but usign barplots? I asked just that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262916/how-i-get-a-facet-grid-plot-with-free-scales-and-barplots-with-ggplot2)

Comment: I feel this does not resolve the issue. I am having the same problem, and all "cyl ~ ." did was flip the axes. Now, the x axis is what I want to be free, but it is not free. I am using R version 3.2.3 with ggplot2 version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 56):

I'm sorry for jumping on this 12 year old question with a new answer, but I think it might be useful. If you want to preserve the grid layout, but want wrap-like free scales, you might be interested in `ggh4x::facet_grid2()` which has an `independent` argument that lets an axis vary within a row or column in a grid-layout.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(. ~ cyl, scales = "free_y", independent = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x)

Comment: Very neat solution, nicely written package! Thanks!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question. ggh4x is great, thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. If I could upvote your answer (and your package) twice, I would!

Comment: Excellent extension, love the `independent` parameter!

Comment: I just discovered `ggh4x` from this answer, I think I'm a kid in the candy store... `scale_colour_multi`!

Answer (score 40):

You can't. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1152)

You can use `facet_wrap` instead, which will 'free' both axes

Answer (score 22):

Hopefully, this helps.

```
mt + facet_wrap(. ~ cyl, scales="free_y")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/facet_grid2.html.

This code allows to make the scales of each panel independent using facet_grid, but with facet_grid2.

Comment: It's helpful to show the actual code that should be used rather than just providing a link