# Plot random effects from lmer (lme4 package) using qqmath or dotplot: How to make it look fancy?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, random-effects

The qqmath function makes great caterpillar plots of random effects using the output from the lmer package.  That is, qqmath is great at plotting the intercepts from a hierarchical model with their errors around the point estimate.  An example of the lmer and qqmath functions are below using the built-in data in the lme4 package called Dyestuff.  The code will produce the hierarchical model and a nice plot using the ggmath function.

```
library("lme4")
data(package = "lme4")

# Dyestuff 
# a balanced one-way classiï¬cation of Yield 
# from samples produced from six Batches

summary(Dyestuff)             

# Batch is an example of a random effect
# Fit 1-way random effects linear model
fit1 <- lmer(Yield ~ 1 + (1|Batch), Dyestuff) 
summary(fit1)
coef(fit1) #intercept for each level in Batch 

# qqplot of the random effects with their variances
qqmath(ranef(fit1, postVar = TRUE), strip = FALSE)$Batch
```

The last line of code produces a really nice plot of each intercept with the error around each estimate.  But formatting the qqmath function seems to be very difficult, and I've been struggling to format the plot.  I've come up with a few questions that I cannot answer, and that I think others could also benefit from if they are using the lmer/qqmath combination:

1. Is there a way to take the qqmath function above and add a few
   options, such as, making certain points empty vs. filled-in, or
   different colors for different points?  For example, can you make the points for A,B, and C of the Batch variable filled, but then the rest of the points empty?
2. Is it possible to add axis labels for each point (maybe along the
   top or right y axis, for example)?
3. My data has closer to 45 intercepts, so it is possible to add
   spacing between the labels so they do not run into each other? 
   MAINLY, I am interested in distinguishing/labeling between points on the
   graph, which seems to be cumbersome/impossible in the ggmath function.

So far, adding any additional option in the qqmath function produce errors where I would not get errors if it was a standard plot, so I'm at a loss.

Also, if you feel there is a better package/function for plotting intercepts from lmer output, I'd love to hear it! (for example, can you do points 1-3 using dotplot?)

**EDIT:** I'm also open to an alternative dotplot if it can be reasonably formatted.  I just like the look of a ggmath plot, so I'm starting with a question about that.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One possibility is to use library `ggplot2` to draw similar graph and then you can adjust appearance of your plot.

First, `ranef` object is saved as `randoms`. Then variances of intercepts are saved in object `qq`.

```
randoms<-ranef(fit1, postVar = TRUE)
qq <- attr(ranef(fit1, postVar = TRUE)[[1]], "postVar")
```

Object `rand.interc` contains just random intercepts with level names.

```
rand.interc<-randoms$Batch
```

All objects put in one data frame. For error intervals `sd.interc` is calculated as 2 times square root of variance.

```
df<-data.frame(Intercepts=randoms$Batch[,1],
              sd.interc=2*sqrt(qq[,,1:length(qq)]),
              lev.names=rownames(rand.interc))
```

If you need that intercepts are ordered in plot according to value then `lev.names` should be reordered. This line can be skipped if intercepts should be ordered by level names.

```
df$lev.names<-factor(df$lev.names,levels=df$lev.names[order(df$Intercepts)])
```

This code produces plot. Now points will differ by `shape` according to factor levels.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(lev.names,Intercepts,shape=lev.names))

#Added horizontal line at y=0, error bars to points and points with size two
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0) +geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Intercepts-sd.interc, ymax=Intercepts+sd.interc), width=0,color="black") + geom_point(aes(size=2)) 

#Removed legends and with scale_shape_manual point shapes set to 1 and 16
p <- p + guides(size=FALSE,shape=FALSE) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,1,1,16,16,16))

#Changed appearance of plot (black and white theme) and x and y axis labels
p <- p + theme_bw() + xlab("Levels") + ylab("")

#Final adjustments of plot
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
               axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1.3)),
               axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
               panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
               panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())

#To put levels on y axis you just need to use coord_flip()
p <- p+ coord_flip()
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This looks great.  But before I give the bounty, I'm getting two errors that says: could not find function "guides" & could not find function "theme" from your plot code.  I have libraries for ggplot2 and scales on, but I still get the errors.  Any idea why that would be? Are these a different package? I can still print a plot but it isn't identical because of the errors.  Also, is it possible to flip the axes so that the levels are on the Y axis (and the error bars would be horizontal)?

Comment: You should update your version of ggplot (and scales). There have been major changes in the most recent versions, including the use of `theme` (instead of `opts`)

Comment: hmm, I updated all my packages, and it still doesn't work.  I tried shutting down R before re-trying too; also tried the code in R Studio but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @CaptainMurphy, what version of ggplot2 does sessionInfo() say you have?  The above code should work with a recent version of ggplot2.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Updated my solution to flip axes. This plot was produced with ggplot2 version 0.9.3. To use this version of ggplot2, your R version should be at least 2.14.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm running ggplot2_0.8.9, so that is the problem.  I'm surprised R Studio didn't catch the ggplot update.  I'll find a way to update though.  Love the flipped axis.  Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: Ahhh, I was running an old version of R, which is why it was pulling the old version of ggplot during installation. I needed to update base R first. Cheers all.

Comment: Now that `postVar` is deprecated, how does this change the answer?

Comment: @mohvd: postVar is deprecated per ?ranef, but note that you can use condVar, i.e.,  
"a (deprecated) synonym for condVar"; the other point of confusion is that the relevant attribute is still named postVar despite using the new condVar name

Answer (score 44):

Didzis' answer is great! Just to wrap it up a little bit, I put it into its own function that behaves a lot like `qqmath.ranef.mer()` and `dotplot.ranef.mer()`. In addition to Didzis' answer, it also handles models with multiple correlated random effects (like `qqmath()` and `dotplot()` do). Comparison to `qqmath()`:

```
require(lme4)                            ## for lmer(), sleepstudy
require(lattice)                         ## for dotplot()
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE))  ## using ggplot2
qqmath(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE))         ## for comparison
```

[image]

Comparison to `dotplot()`:

```
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE)
dotplot(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE))
```

[image]

Sometimes, it might be useful to have different scales for the random effects - something which `dotplot()` enforces. When I tried to relax this, I had to change the facetting (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685496)).

```
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=FALSE)
```

[image]

```
## re = object of class ranef.mer
ggCaterpillar <- function(re, QQ=TRUE, likeDotplot=TRUE) {
    require(ggplot2)
    f <- function(x) {
        pv   <- attr(x, "postVar")
        cols <- 1:(dim(pv)[1])
        se   <- unlist(lapply(cols, function(i) sqrt(pv[i, i, ])))
        ord  <- unlist(lapply(x, order)) + rep((0:(ncol(x) - 1)) * nrow(x), each=nrow(x))
        pDf  <- data.frame(y=unlist(x)[ord],
                           ci=1.96*se[ord],
                           nQQ=rep(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(x))), ncol(x)),
                           ID=factor(rep(rownames(x), ncol(x))[ord], levels=rownames(x)[ord]),
                           ind=gl(ncol(x), nrow(x), labels=names(x)))

        if(QQ) {  ## normal QQ-plot
            p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(nQQ, y))
            p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind, scales="free")
            p <- p + xlab("Standard normal quantiles") + ylab("Random effect quantiles")
        } else {  ## caterpillar dotplot
            p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(ID, y)) + coord_flip()
            if(likeDotplot) {  ## imitate dotplot() -> same scales for random effects
                p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind)
            } else {           ## different scales for random effects
                p <- p + facet_grid(ind ~ ., scales="free_y")
            }
            p <- p + xlab("Levels") + ylab("Random effects")
        }

        p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
        p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
        p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=0, colour="black")
        p <- p + geom_point(aes(size=1.2), colour="blue") 
        return(p)
    }

    lapply(re, f)
}
```

Comment: This works incredibly well. But what about producing an output table, say for latex?

Comment: @caracal when you do 1.96*se[ord] why do you not need to take into account the number of observations in each group?

Comment: Great function, in the meanwhile throws a warning, though. But due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126203/6574038) we just have to slightly change the call to `ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=FALSE)`.

Comment: @jaySf Thanks for the heads up! Fixed.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do this is to extract simulated values from the distribution of each of the random effects and plot those. Using the `merTools` package, it is possible to easily get the simulations from a `lmer` or `glmer` object, and to plot them.

```
library(lme4); library(merTools)       ## for lmer(), sleepstudy
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
randoms <- REsim(fit, n.sims = 500)
```

`randoms` is now an object with that looks like:

```
head(randoms)
groupFctr groupID        term       mean     median       sd
1   Subject     308 (Intercept)   3.083375   2.214805 14.79050
2   Subject     309 (Intercept) -39.382557 -38.607697 12.68987
3   Subject     310 (Intercept) -37.314979 -38.107747 12.53729
4   Subject     330 (Intercept)  22.234687  21.048882 11.51082
5   Subject     331 (Intercept)  21.418040  21.122913 13.17926
6   Subject     332 (Intercept)  11.371621  12.238580 12.65172
```

It provides the name of the grouping factor, the level of the factor we are obtaining an estimate for, the term in the model, and the mean, median, and standard deviation of the simulated values. We can use this to generate a caterpillar plot similar to those above:

```
plotREsim(randoms)
```

Which produces:

[image: A caterpillar plot of random effects]

One nice feature is that the values that have a confidence interval that does not overlap zero are highlighted in black. You can modify the width of the interval by using the `level` parameter to `plotREsim` making wider or narrower confidence intervals based on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to obtain the desired plot is through the `plot_model()`command integraded in the `sjPlot`package. The advantage is that the command returns a `ggplot`-object and hence there are many options to adjust the figure as wished. I kept the example simple because there are many options to individualize the visualisation - just check `?plot_model`for all options.

```
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
#?plot_model

data(Dyestuff, package = "lme4")
summary(Dyestuff)             

fit1 <- lmer(Yield ~ 1 + (1|Batch), Dyestuff) 
summary(fit1)

plot_model(fit1, type="re",
           vline.color="#A9A9A9", dot.size=1.5,
           show.values=T, value.offset=.2)
```

[image: The output of the example given above:]