# Plotting random intercepts of clmm

Tags: r, ordinal, ggplot2

I'm having trouble plotting random intercepts from a `clmm()` model with 4 random effects in 31 countries.

I tried following this SO post: [In R, plotting random effects from lmer (lme4 package) using qqmath or dotplot: how to make it look fancy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847936/in-r-plotting-random-effects-from-lmer-lme4-package-using-qqmath-or-dotplot) However, I cannot get the confidence intervals to show up. I've managed to use `dotchart` to plot the intercepts by country.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ordinal)

 # create data frame with intercepts and variances of all random effects
 # the first column are the grouping factor, followed by 5 columns of intercepts, 
 # columns 7-11 are the variances.
randoms <- as.data.frame(ranef(nodual.logit, condVar = F))
var     <- as.data.frame(condVar(nodual.logit))
df      <- merge(randoms, var, by ="row.names")

 # calculate the CI
df[,7:11] <- (1.96*(sqrt(df[,7:11])/sqrt(length(df[,1]))))

 # dot plot of intercepts and CI.
p <- ggplot(df,aes(as.factor(Row.names),df[,2]))
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
     geom_errorbar(aes(xmax=df[,2]+df[,7], xmin=df[,2]-df[,7]), width=0, color="black") + 
     geom_point(aes(size=2))
p <- p + coord_flip()
print(p)
```

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Here is another way I tried to plot them:

```
D <- dotchart(df[,2], labels = df[,1])
D <- D + geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=df[,2]+df[,7], xmin=df[,2]-df[,7],))
```

> Error in dotchart(df[, 2], labels = df[, 1]) + geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = df[,  :    non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution based on [R.H.B Christensen (2013) “A Tutorial on fitting Cumulative Link Mixed Models with clmm2 from the ordinal Package”](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tutorial.pdf) pg. 5.

First plot intercept points for all 31 countries, the add labels using `axis()`, then add CI’s using `segments()`.

```
plot(1:31,df[,2], ylim=range(df[,2]), axes =F, ylab ="intercept") 
abline(h = 0, lty=2)
axis(1, at=1:31, labels = df[,1], las =2)
axis(2, at= seq(-2,2, by=.5))
for(i in 1:31) segments(i, df[i,2]+df[i,7], i, df[i,2]-df[i, 7])
```

Can put this code into another loop to plot the Betas of the random effects

```
for(n in 2:6) plot(1:31,df[,n], ylim=range(df[,n]),axes =F, ylab =colnames(df[n]))+
abline(h = 0, lty=2)+
axis(1, at=1:31, labels = df[,1], las =2)+
axis(2, at= seq(-2,2, by=.5))+
for(i in 1:31) segments(i, df[i,n]+df[i,(n+5)], i, df[i,n]-df[i, (n+5)])
```