# Can not change lay-out of dotplot() (lattice package) based on ranef(lmerMod)

Tags: r, lattice, lme4

We're trying to use dotplot to create a caterpillarplot based on the random effect structure of a `lmerMod` object created by `lmer()` in the lme4 package.

The plot itself is created perfectly fine, but when trying to change the lay-out errors occur.

Sample of code without lay-out instructions:

```
all_bv_C <- lmer(RQ_EvT_A ~ SD_Lft_M_Cat4 + SD_Opl_M_Cat3 + OV_Gez_M_4 +   (1|VSVnr), data=BV2, REML=TRUE)

random <- ranef(all_bv_C, condVar = TRUE)

dotplot(randoms, scales = list(x = list(relation = 'free')))
```

This creates the plot:

[image: dotplot]

We wish to change the title, axis labels and the color palette. For example, to change the title, the usual syntax would be

```
dotplot(randoms, scales = list(x = list(relation = 'free')), main="Title")
```

This throws the error:

> Error in if (main) nx : argument is not interpretable as logical

We've been unable to get around this error. Everywhere we looked, this should work for any dotplot usage. Can anyone shed some light?

P.S.: We're using `dotplot()` over `ggplot()` due to some irregularities in extracting the random effect structure into a data frame as would be suggested here: [ggCaterpillar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847936/in-r-plotting-random-effects-from-lmer-lme4-package-using-qqmath-or-dotplot). The function specified throws a NULL due to:

```
pv   <- attr(x, "postVar")
```

We've also tried other routes for extracting the variance/covariance matrix to adapt the function, but felt that dotplot was the easier route after fumbling for a day.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not here without changing the code. Looking at the source code of the S3 method `dotplot` for `ranef.mer` class:

```
getS3method("dotplot","ranef.mer")
```

You can not set the titles suing arguments. If you look in the function in some line it is written explicitly:

```
 mtit <- if (main) nx
```

where nx is the names(x)( your ranef object).

So if you do  somthing like :

```
names(randoms) <- "Title" 
dotplot(randoms)
```

the plot title will change. But this is a hack. Better here to change the code of the function and customize it as you like.

Comment: Wow, I never knew I could look at the source code like that. A whole new world. The function that is shown in the console, is the exact function of dotplot when combined with a ranef.mer object? That is really neat and should give me plenty of ways to customize it. Thanks!

Comment: @kneijenhuijs yes the function is what you see in the console.You can copy and paste it and do the customization. The function name is `dotplot.ranef.mer`(You should keep this name)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else sees this, a simpler solution would be to create the dotplot object first, and then change the title using the $ operator:

```
dp <- dotplot(randoms, scales = list(x = list(relation = 'free')))
dp$VSVnr$main <- "Title"
```