# How can I sort random effects by value of the random effect (not the intercept) in dotplot or ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, lme4

I suspect the answer to this question is rather simple and I just don't know what it is.

Long story short, I want to display a dotplot of the random intercepts and slopes from a model I am estimating. I'm using the `ggCaterpillar` function helpfully introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847936/in-r-plotting-random-effects-from-lmer-lme4-package-using-qqmath-or-dotplot). However, this function, as well as the standard `dotplot` from lattice, sort the ensuing graph by decreasing order of the random intercept. I would like to sort the graph by increasing value of the random effect (either alphabetical or numerical).

Consider this minimum working example that comes standard in the `lme4` package, along with the `ggCaterpillar` function.

```
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847936/in-r-plotting-random-effects-from-lmer-lme4-package-using-qqmath-or-dotplot
ggCaterpillar <- function(re, QQ=TRUE, likeDotplot=TRUE) {
    require(ggplot2)
f <- function(x) {
    pv   <- attr(x, "postVar")
    cols <- 1:(dim(pv)[1])
    se   <- unlist(lapply(cols, function(i) sqrt(pv[i, i, ])))
    ord  <- unlist(lapply(x, order)) + rep((0:(ncol(x) - 1)) * nrow(x), each=nrow(x))
    pDf  <- data.frame(y=unlist(x)[ord],
                       ci=1.96*se[ord],
                       nQQ=rep(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(x))), ncol(x)),
                       ID=factor(rep(rownames(x), ncol(x))[ord], levels=rownames(x)[ord]),
                       ind=gl(ncol(x), nrow(x), labels=names(x)))

    if(QQ) {  ## normal QQ-plot
        p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(nQQ, y))
        p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind, scales="free")
        p <- p + xlab("Standard normal quantiles") + ylab("Random effect quantiles")
    } else {  ## caterpillar dotplot
        p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(ID, y)) + coord_flip()
        if(likeDotplot) {  ## imitate dotplot() -> same scales for random effects
            p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind)
        } else {           ## different scales for random effects
            p <- p + facet_grid(ind ~ ., scales="free_y")
        }
        p <- p + xlab("Levels") + ylab("Random effects")
    }

    p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
    p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
    p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=0, colour="black")
    p <- p + geom_point(aes(size=1.2), colour="blue") 
    return(p)
}

lapply(re, f)
}

library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit,condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=TRUE)[["Subject"]]
```

The graph I get looks like this.

[image: Sample graph]

How can I order the graph so the plots are ordered by increasing value of the random effect (e.g. 308, 309, 310... in the sleepstudy case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the part of the function where `ord` and `pDf` are created the rows are reordered by size of the intercept. We can make that part optional like in the updated function below:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggCaterpillar <- function(re, QQ=TRUE, likeDotplot=TRUE, reorder=TRUE) {
  require(ggplot2)
  f <- function(x) {
    pv   <- attr(x, "postVar")
    cols <- 1:(dim(pv)[1])
    se   <- unlist(lapply(cols, function(i) sqrt(pv[i, i, ])))
    if (reorder) {
      ord  <- unlist(lapply(x, order)) + rep((0:(ncol(x) - 1)) * nrow(x), each=nrow(x))
      pDf  <- data.frame(y=unlist(x)[ord],
                         ci=1.96*se[ord],
                         nQQ=rep(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(x))), ncol(x)),
                         ID=factor(rep(rownames(x), ncol(x))[ord], levels=rownames(x)[ord]),
                         ind=gl(ncol(x), nrow(x), labels=names(x)))
    } else {
      pDf  <- data.frame(y=unlist(x),
                         ci=1.96*se,
                         nQQ=rep(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(x))), ncol(x)),
                         ID=factor(rep(rownames(x), ncol(x)), levels=rownames(x)),
                         ind=gl(ncol(x), nrow(x), labels=names(x)))
    }

    if(QQ) {  ## normal QQ-plot
      p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(nQQ, y))
      p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind, scales="free")
      p <- p + xlab("Standard normal quantiles") + ylab("Random effect quantiles")
    } else {  ## caterpillar dotplot
      p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(ID, y)) + coord_flip()
      if(likeDotplot) {  ## imitate dotplot() -> same scales for random effects
        p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind)
      } else {           ## different scales for random effects
        p <- p + facet_grid(ind ~ ., scales="free_y")
      }
      p <- p + xlab("Levels") + ylab("Random effects")
    }

    p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
    p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
    p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=0, colour="black")
    p <- p + geom_point(aes(size=1.2), colour="blue") 
    return(p)
  }

  lapply(re, f)
}
```

If we now call the function with `reorder = FALSE` we get the original order of the rows:

```
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit,condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=TRUE, reorder=FALSE)[["Subject"]]
```

[image]

You can reorder rows before plotting if you'd like, for example to reverse the order:

```
ref <- ranef(fit,condVar=TRUE)
ref$Subject <- ref$Subject[nrow(ref$Subject):1, ]
ggCaterpillar(ref, QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=TRUE, reorder=FALSE)[["Subject"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.