# A caterpillar plot of just the "significant" random effects from a mixed effects model

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I've had great experiences asking for help here before and I'm hoping to get some help again.

I'm estimating a rather large mixed effects model in which one of the random effects has over 150 different levels. That would make a standard caterpillar plot to be quite unreadable.

I would like, if all possible, to get a caterpillar plot of just the levels of the random effect that are, for a lack of better term, "significant". That is: I want a caterpillar plot in which either the random intercept **or** the random slope for a varying coefficient has a "confidence interval" (I know that's not quite what it is) that does not include zero.

Consider this standard model from the `sleepstudy` data that is standard with `lme4`.

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit,condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=TRUE, reorder=FALSE)[["Subject"]]
```

I would get this caterpillar plot.

[image: a caterpillar plot]

The caterpillar plot I use comes from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120578/how-can-i-sort-random-effects-by-value-of-the-random-effect-not-the-intercept). Do note I tend to use less conservative bounds for the intervals (i.e. 1.645*se and not 1.96*se).

Basically, I want a caterpillar plot that would just include the levels for 308, 309, 310, 330, 331, 335, 337, 349, 350, 352, and 370 because those levels had either intercepts **or** slopes whose intervals did not include zero. I ask because my caterpillar plot of over 150 different levels is kind of unreadable and I think this might be a worthwhile solution to it.

Reproducible code follows. I genuinely appreciate any help.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120578/how-can-i-sort-random-effects-by-value-of-the-random-effect-not-the-intercept
ggCaterpillar <- function(re, QQ=TRUE, likeDotplot=TRUE, reorder=TRUE) {
require(ggplot2)
f <- function(x) {
pv   <- attr(x, "postVar")
cols <- 1:(dim(pv)[1])
se   <- unlist(lapply(cols, function(i) sqrt(pv[i, i, ])))
if (reorder) {
  ord  <- unlist(lapply(x, order)) + rep((0:(ncol(x) - 1)) * nrow(x), each=nrow(x))
  pDf  <- data.frame(y=unlist(x)[ord],
                     ci=1.645*se[ord],
                     nQQ=rep(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(x))), ncol(x)),
                     ID=factor(rep(rownames(x), ncol(x))[ord], levels=rownames(x)[ord]),
                     ind=gl(ncol(x), nrow(x), labels=names(x)))
} else {
  pDf  <- data.frame(y=unlist(x),
                     ci=1.645*se,
                     nQQ=rep(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(x))), ncol(x)),
                     ID=factor(rep(rownames(x), ncol(x)), levels=rownames(x)),
                     ind=gl(ncol(x), nrow(x), labels=names(x)))
}

if(QQ) {  ## normal QQ-plot
  p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(nQQ, y))
  p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind, scales="free")
  p <- p + xlab("Standard normal quantiles") + ylab("Random effect quantiles")
} else {  ## caterpillar dotplot
  p <- ggplot(pDf, aes(ID, y)) + coord_flip()
  if(likeDotplot) {  ## imitate dotplot() -> same scales for random effects
    p <- p + facet_wrap(~ ind)
  } else {           ## different scales for random effects
    p <- p + facet_grid(ind ~ ., scales="free_y")
  }
  p <- p + xlab("Levels of the Random Effect") + ylab("Random Effect")
}

p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), width=0, colour="black")
p <- p + geom_point(aes(size=1.2), colour="blue") 
return(p)
}

  lapply(re, f)
}


library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
ggCaterpillar(ranef(fit,condVar=TRUE), QQ=FALSE, likeDotplot=TRUE, reorder=FALSE)[["Subject"]] 
ggsave(file="sleepstudy.png")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, thanks for putting "significant" in quotation marks ... everyone reading this should remember that significance doesn't have any *statistical* meaning in this context (it might be better to use a Z-statistic (value/std.error) criterion such as |Z|>1.5 or |Z|>1.75 instead, just to emphasize that this is *not* an inferential threshold ...)

I ended up getting a little carried away  ... I decided that it would be better to refactor/modularize things a little bit, so I wrote an `augment` method (designed to work with the `broom` package) that constructs useful data frames from `ranef.mer` objects ... once this is done, the manipulations you want are pretty easy.

I put the `augment.ranef.mer` code at the end of my answer -- it's a bit long (you'll need to source it before you can run the code here).  **update**: this `augment` method has been part of the `broom.mixed` package for a while now ...

```
library(broom)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
```

Apply the `augment` method to the RE object:

```
rr <- ranef(fit,condVar=TRUE)
aa <- augment(rr)

names(aa)
## [1] "grp"       "variable"  "level"     "estimate"  "qq"        "std.error"
## [7] "p"         "lb"        "ub"
```

Now the `ggplot` code is pretty basic.  I'm using `geom_errorbarh(height=0)` rather than `geom_pointrange()+coord_flip()` because `ggplot2` can't use `coord_flip` with `facet_wrap(...,scales="free")` ...

```
## Q-Q plot:
g0 <- ggplot(aa,aes(estimate,qq,xmin=lb,xmax=ub))+
    geom_errorbarh(height=0)+
    geom_point()+facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")

## regular caterpillar plot:
g1 <- ggplot(aa,aes(estimate,level,xmin=lb,xmax=ub))+
    geom_errorbarh(height=0)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=0,lty=2)+
    geom_point()+facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")
```

Now find the levels you want to keep:

```
aa2 <- ddply(aa,c("grp","level"),
             transform,
             keep=any(p<0.05))
aa3 <- subset(aa2,keep)
```

Update caterpillar plot with only levels with "significant" slopes or intercepts:

```
g1 %+% aa3
```

If you only wanted to highlight "significant" levels rather than removing "non-significant" levels entirely

```
ggplot(aa2,aes(estimate,level,xmin=lb,xmax=ub,colour=factor(keep)))+
    geom_errorbarh(height=0)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=0,lty=2)+
    geom_point()+facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")+
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","red"),guide=FALSE)
```

---

```
##' @importFrom reshape2 melt
##' @importFrom plyr ldply name_rows 
augment.ranef.mer <- function(x,
                                 ci.level=0.9,
                                 reorder=TRUE,
                                 order.var=1) {
    tmpf <- function(z) {
        if (is.character(order.var) && !order.var %in% names(z)) {
            order.var <- 1
            warning("order.var not found, resetting to 1")
        }
        ## would use plyr::name_rows, but want levels first
        zz <- data.frame(level=rownames(z),z,check.names=FALSE)
        if (reorder) {
            ## if numeric order var, add 1 to account for level column
            ov <- if (is.numeric(order.var)) order.var+1 else order.var
            zz$level <- reorder(zz$level, zz[,order.var+1], FUN=identity)
        }
        ## Q-Q values, for each column separately
        qq <- c(apply(z,2,function(y) {
                  qnorm(ppoints(nrow(z)))[order(order(y))]
              }))
        rownames(zz) <- NULL
        pv   <- attr(z, "postVar")
        cols <- 1:(dim(pv)[1])
        se   <- unlist(lapply(cols, function(i) sqrt(pv[i, i, ])))
        ## n.b.: depends on explicit column-major ordering of se/melt
        zzz <- cbind(melt(zz,id.vars="level",value.name="estimate"),
                     qq=qq,std.error=se)
        ## reorder columns:
        subset(zzz,select=c(variable, level, estimate, qq, std.error))
    }
    dd <- ldply(x,tmpf,.id="grp")
    ci.val <- -qnorm((1-ci.level)/2)
    transform(dd,
              p=2*pnorm(-abs(estimate/std.error)), ## 2-tailed p-val
              lb=estimate-ci.val*std.error,
              ub=estimate+ci.val*std.error)
}
```

Comment: "I ended up getting a little carried away ..." Heh, heh. You ain't kidding. Awesome answer!

Comment: Heh, I've read the `lme4` message boards  long enough to know better than to seriously use "confidence intervals" and "significant" in the context of random effects. :P

And this was an excellent answer. I did not know about the `broom` package either. Thanks again!

Comment: Ben this is great! Would you mind if I added it to your many broom contributions?