# How I get a facet_grid plot, with free scales AND barplots, with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm (re)learning `ggplot2` and trying to get this particular
plot, which is proving quite evasive.

Earlier I found [this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685285/ggplot2-facet-grid-free-scales),
which was useful, but not everything I need. This is more or less what you get
using the accepted answer to that Q:

```
## Packages & data:
require(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(categ=c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 V1=rpois(3, 20), 
                 V2=rnorm(3, 100, 40), 
                 V2=runif(3)) %>% gather(Var, X, 2:4)
## Se below in "Example data" for how to get this example

p  <- ggplot(df, aes(categ, X, color=Var)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(Var ~ ., scale="free")
```

The resulting plot is this:

[image]

However, I need to do the same, only with barplots instead of just points.
Anyone with some help?

Thanks in advance,
Juan

#### Example data

Note that I used `tidyr::ghather` and `magrittr`'s pipe `%>%` to create my
example, but the same can be achieved with `reshape2::melt`:

```
require(reshape2)
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(categ=c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 V1=rpois(3, 20), 
                 V2=rnorm(3, 100, 40), 
                 V2=runif(3))
df <- melt(df, id="categ", variable.name="Var", value.name="X")
```

Anyway, the resultant `data.frame` looks like this:

```
categ  Var           X
    A   V1  25.0000000
    B   V1  18.0000000
    C   V1  25.0000000
    A   V2 150.8971729
    B   V2 116.5856574
    C   V2  38.4019983
    A V2.1   0.1765568
    B V2.1   0.6870228
    C V2.1   0.3841037
```

Comment: Barplots really don't make a lot of sense unless they are referenced to a 0 line.

Comment: Indeed, but that wouldn't be a problem (you just change the lower extreme of the scale), would it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was simpler that I thought, I just needed to add `stat = "identity"` on the `geom_bar` call:

```
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(categ, X, color=Var)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p + facet_grid(Var ~ ., scale="free")
```

[image: Colors are still not quite good, but that's easier to fix, I hope...]