# free y axis in ggplot2 using facet_grid()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

Here is a part of my code to plot my data using ggplot2 and bellow you can see the resulting plot.

```
ggplot(dd_all, aes(x=sequence, y=value) + geom_line() + geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('orange', 'red', 'blue','sky blue','dark green'),labels=c('MLR', 'ANN', 'M5','M5 Bag','RF')) +
  facet_grid(measure ~ period, switch ='y', scales = "free")
```

[image]

I would like to use different (y) scales for each of my (eight) plots. Using `scales = 'free'` or `scales = 'free_y'`, I only manage to get different scales for each row. However, I would like to get different scales for validation and calibration data (e.g. right and left column).

Why I would like to do that, is probable obvious.

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685285/ggplot2-facet-grid-free-scales), but no solution was given.

Comment: The linked question has an accepted answer with 20 upvotes.

Comment: use `facet_wrap()`

Comment: Yes of course... I should pay more attention to the comments. My appologise. Tnx for your help.