# ggplot: create a facet grid with free scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot I want to create a facet grid where the y axes are free. This `scales` option is available in `facet_wrap()` but I want to keep the grid layout. I have attached a drawn example of what I want.

[image: example of facet grid with free y axes]

EDIT:
I added some code for calrity

```
# Create data
nX <- 3
nY <- 3
nVal <- 2
df <- data.frame(M = sort(rep(paste0("M",1:nX), nVal * nY)),
                 n = rep(sort(paste0("n",rep((1:nY)-1, nVal))),nX),
                 G = rep(1:2,nX * nY),
                 val = c(100,300,20,10,1,2,10,25,NA,NA,0.1,0.2,25,27,2,5,0.5,0.6))

# Delete observations to resemble my data
df <- subset(df, !is.na(val))

# scales does not work in facet_grid(), thus obscuring trends for low values
ggplot(df, aes(x = G,
               y = val)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylim(0,NA)+
  facet_grid(n ~ M,scales = "free_y")
```

[image: with facet grid]

Note that no trends are visible for low values because in the grid they are obscured by the high values.

```
# the grid is lost in facet_wrap()
ggplot(df, aes(x = G,
               y = val)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylim(0,NA)+
  facet_wrap(n+M~.,scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Note that the grid layout is lost.

Comment: Any code available?

Comment: Unfortunately no. What I need is something in between facet_grid and facet_wrap. It might look something like this `p <- p + facet_grid(n ~ m, scales = "free_y" )`

Comment: @TarJae I added some code.

Comment: Maybe you could use the {patchwork} package, build your 6 labels and 9 charts separately then stitch it all together

Comment: Yes I could do that but it feels so _hacky_ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dev/github version of ggh4x has [`facet_grid2()`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#grid-1) which allows these independent axes within a grid layout. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.) If you find any bugs or unclear documentation, feel free to leave an issue on the github since I don't think this has been field-tested a lot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x) # devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x")

# Create data
nX <- 3
nY <- 3
nVal <- 2
df <- data.frame(M = sort(rep(paste0("M",1:nX), nVal * nY)),
                 n = rep(sort(paste0("n",rep((1:nY)-1, nVal))),nX),
                 G = rep(1:2,nX * nY),
                 val = c(100,300,20,10,1,2,10,25,NA,NA,0.1,0.2,25,27,2,5,0.5,0.6))

# Delete observations to resemble my data
df <- subset(df, !is.na(val))

# scales does not work in facet_grid(), thus obscuring trends for low values
ggplot(df, aes(x = G,
               y = val)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylim(0,NA)+
  facet_grid2(n ~ M,scales = "free_y", independent = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This look great! I'm gonna try it out and let you know.

Comment: This really fills a gap in ggplot, thank you!

Comment: Hello, I have a problem with the package. I now want the y-axis has the same scale within each column and different between columns. How am I able to achieve this? i.e., i want scales to fixed in y but I want independent y

Comment: That sounds like two contradictory goals to me. Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn’t possible by default - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685285/ggplot2-facet-grid-free-scales) for more info. Probably some approach using {patchwork} is your best bet, but there are also other other approaches you can take if you’re willing to look under the hood of {ggplot2}, for example the one outlined [here](https://fishandwhistle.net/post/2018/modifying-facet-scales-in-ggplot2/)