# ggplot2, facet grid with free scales and spaces

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid

I hadn't plotted much with R so far, I want to facet the plot with free scales and spaces.
What I tried so far is

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x = Scores, y = Value)) +
  geom_bar( aes(fill=Input),
            stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()
  ) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#EFC000FF","#868686FF", "#0073C2FF", "#CD534CFF"))+ theme_pubr() +
facet_grid(. ~ Group, scales = "free", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

So I cant get the free y scales. This is probably trivial, but I didn't find anything that compares.

Comment: Hi Qwap! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit your question to make it a reproducible one? Thanks a bunch !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2, facet\_grid, free scales?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685285/ggplot2-facet-grid-free-scales)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get free `"y"` scales by `facet_grid()` for each row, but if you insisted on it, you could try using `facet_grid2()` from {ggh4x} package.

For example:

```r
# install.packages("ggh4x")
ggplot(df3, aes(x = Scores, y = Value)) +
  geom_bar( aes(fill=Input),
            stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()
  ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#EFC000FF","#868686FF", "#0073C2FF", "#CD534CFF")) + 
  theme_pubr() +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(. ~ Group, independent = "y", scales = "free", space = "free_x")
```

See [this manual](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#grid) for more information.

Comment: You are welcome! We should say thanks to the author of ggh4x, too. :-)